# android studio problems - gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I recently encountered a problem in Android Studio: When I open the build.Gradle-Project file of my old projects, instead of the usual text, it says:

```
 ���� 4 � com / example / recyclerview / R $ dimen java / lang / Object com / example / recyclerview / R dimen% abc_action_bar_content_inset_material I % abc_action_bar_content_inset_with_nav & abc_action_bar_default_height_material + abc_action_bar_default_padding_end_material -abc_action_bar_default_padding_start_material! abc_action_bar_ebarvation
```

When I say old, I mean a few months ago.
It should be noted that I have recently migrated to AndroidX. Could it be a problem with immigration? Or from somewhere else?
Alternatively, there is a notification above it that I do not know which one to click.

Here is his photo:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuB0z.png)

Comment: Have you tried invalided cache and restart

Comment: It's telling you the problem. The ecoding is different, so choose another one and try